# Update a network request in Corona SDK

Tags: networking, sdk, lua, request, coronasdk

I am fetching some json stuff(value of bitcoin) from a website with the network.request-function. However, I want that json stuff(value of bitcoin) to update to the latest version every time the user presses update. How would that be possible?

```
local json = require("json")
btcPriceText = display.newText("price", 50,100, "Arial", 25)

local function btcValue(event)
btcValue = json.decode(event.response)
dollarbtc= btcValue[1]['rate']
end

local function update()
if(dollarbtc) then
    btcPriceText.text = "BTC"..dollarbtc
end
end


network.request( "https://bitpay.com/api/rates", "GET", btcValue )
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", update )
```

This is all the code I'm using.

Comment: can you post the code for your scene and update button? you could put the request in handler but without seeing code it's hard to tell if this is best way for you

Comment: Schollii: I posted my code up there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the excellent [Corona docs on buttons](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newButton.html) page, you would put your `network.request` in the `handleButtonEvent` of the first example on that page. This way, every time the user clicks button, a new request is made. As soon as response arrives, the `btcValue` function will get called, thus setting the `dollarbtc` value based on the content of the response. Currently your `update` callback checks at every time frame whether the response data is available. So at very least, you should unset dollarbtc (set it to nil) after you update the text widget, otherwise you will be updating the widget at every time frame!

```
local function update()
    if (dollarbtc) then
        btcPriceText.text = "BTC"..dollarbtc
        dollarbtc = nil -- do come here again, text field updated!
    end
end
```

However, you don't even need to do that: update the text field when handling the response:

```
local function btcValue(event)
    local btcValue = json.decode(event.response)
    local dollarbtc= btcValue[1]['rate']
    btcPriceText.text = "BTC"..dollarbtc
end
```

and you can forget about the `Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", update )` line, no longer needed.

Don't forget to add a `display.yourButton:addEventListener( "tap", handleButtonEvent)` so the button [responds to clicks](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/tap/index.html). The tap event does not have phases (whereas the touch event does).